# How do I copy smart objects from one opened file to another

Tags: software, photoshop

Lets say I have two opened images I am working on in Photo Shop.  I want to copy an entire layer or a smart object from one opened image to the other opened image.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a layer:

In your original image right click the layer in the list and select the "Duplicate Layer..." option.

You get a dialog prompting for the new layer name and (importantly in this case) a Destination drop down. It's defaulted to the current document but you can select another open document or create a new document. If you select another document you can also set it's name.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me (May 24, 2016). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You just drag from the layers tab, the smart object and drop it to the other window with the second photo that you like to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I've not found a consistent way to actually automate this via an action which highly increases the amount of time required for such a simple task.

For now I move the window with the master smart filter applied and manually drag the smart filter object between documents.